# how to refresh returning amx page on return activity

Tags: oracle-maf

In a task flow definition I have a return activity  which is returning me back to previous page. How can a reload data on the page I am returning to. Exact scenario is I am editing a record by selecting one record and opening an other amx page displaying that record. After updating that record I return back to parent view and want to refresh that view so that updated record is displayed. The parent page uses  and  to list records.

Regards,
Mohsin

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow community. Please take some time and complete [Welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you are binding data to view, if you are using data controls to list collection on amx page, you could use managed bean to refresh iterator on that page:

```
    public void refreshIterator(){
    String iterBinding = "#{bindings.entityIterator}";

        ValueExpression vex = AdfmfJavaUtilities.getValueExpression(iterBinding, Object.class);
        AmxIteratorBinding iterator = (AmxIteratorBinding)vex.getValue(AdfmfJavaUtilities.getELContext());
        iterator.getIterator().refresh();       
    }
```